# apply condition on json object with in json array java

Tags: java, android, json

I am fetching some json from server like this

```
    "applications": [
        {
          "packageName": "com.facebook.mlite",
          "defaultPermissionPolicy": "PROMPT",
          "delegatedScopes": [
            "DELEGATED_SCOPE_UNSPECIFIED",
            "CERT_INSTALL",
            "MANAGED_CONFIGURATIONS",
            "BLOCK_UNINSTALL",
            "PERMISSION_GRANT",
            "PACKAGE_ACCESS",
            "ENABLE_SYSTEM_APP"
          ],
          "permissionGrants": [
            {
              "permission": "tt",
              "policy": "PROMPT"
            }
          ],
          "disabled": false,
          "minimumVersionCode": 0
        },


 {
      "packageName": "com.facebook.mlite",
      "defaultPermissionPolicy": "PROMPT",
      "delegatedScopes": [
        "DELEGATED_SCOPE_UNSPECIFIED",
        "CERT_INSTALL",
        "MANAGED_CONFIGURATIONS",
        "BLOCK_UNINSTALL",
        "PERMISSION_GRANT",
        "PACKAGE_ACCESS",
        "ENABLE_SYSTEM_APP"
      ],
      "permissionGrants": [
        {
          "permission": "tt",
        }
      ],
     }
      ]
```

Now there is a json array `"application":[]` in which there are several json object. Now these object are not same. Some json objects are missing like first object contains `installType` but second one doesn't. Now i want to add this in a list for a recyclerview if a json object is missing i want to send empty tring in contrustor of my pojo class

```
   public Application(String defaultPermissionPolicy, List<String> delegatedScopes, List<com.ariaware.enrolldevice.PolicyPojos.PermissionGrants> permissionGrants, Boolean disabled, String installType, Integer minimumVersionCode, String packageName) {
        this.defaultPermissionPolicy = defaultPermissionPolicy;
        this.delegatedScopes = delegatedScopes;
        PermissionGrants = permissionGrants;
        this.disabled = disabled;
        this.installType = installType;
        this.minimumVersionCode = minimumVersionCode;
        this.packageName = packageName;
    }
```

This is constructor of my class. Now how will i loop through json array and check either if an object exists or not or if doesn't exist then send empty string. I need to check every object

Comment: add the code that you use to fetch, what library do you use?

Comment: i m using android managment api to fetch the data ... i m just trying to figuring out to loop through json array and check if json object exist and then add in list class

Comment: Okay then show some code on how do you fetch the data, to know how to help.

Comment: can u come on teamviewer. I can't show whole code here. If u come on teamviewer it will be ease for me

Comment: I want that other people see the problem in your question, I don't want the whole code....I want the part where you get a call back and the response.....just a part of this callback.

Comment: I don't know if u have any idea of android management api. In this api i don't need to send network call . I just import library and use built in functions and those functions return json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could implement another constructor which accepts a `JSONObject` as a parameter and create the object. Inside the constructor use `optString` which returns an empty string if the field doesn't exist (also accepts another parameter for the fallback value).

```
public Application(JSONObject jsonObject) {
    this.installType = jsonObject.optString("installType");

    // example of an array
    JSONArray scopes = jsonObject.optJSONArray("delegatedScopes");
    this.delegatedScopes = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < scopes.length(); i++)
        this.delegatedScopes.add(scopes.optString(i));

    //other initialization...
}
```

Finally, you retrieve each `JSONObject` from the `applications` array.

```
try {
    JSONArray res = data.optJSONArray("applications");
    Application[] items =  new Application[res.length()];
    for (int i = 0; i < res.length(); i++)
        items[i] = new Application(res.getJSONObject(i));
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: let me try for it and then tell u response back

Comment: and what about json array inside json object

Comment: As it's inside the JSONObject, you have access to it in the constructor. Let me edit the answer.

Comment: it is giving me exception `W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: No value for delegatedScopes` . as i told if json object doesn't exist then i need to send empty string

Comment: as i my question i posted json objects can be missing

Comment: In the constructor, I'm initiating the List and add all the scopes to it, if any exists otherwise it will be empty.

Comment: i did n't under stand clearly ...please the json again and modify the answe according to that json plzzzzzzzzzzzz

Comment: It is based on the JSON, where do you have problem?

Comment: brother see the json array permissionGrants in my question this array has further strigs in it..how will i tackle it?